# Perl: Data Input Module Not Working

Tags: perl, perl-module

Below are the contents of two files I am running:
Secure.cgi
MyModule.pm

The “sub scrub{}” subroutine in MyModule.pm was a subroutine in Secure.cgi but I wanted to
run it as a separate module instead.

As a subroutine in Secure.cgi, “sub scrub” worked perfectly but When I moved it to 
MyModule.pm, it does not work -- undoubtedly because I am calling it incorrectly, and 
probably have errors in the module.

This is my first attempt at creating a module.  "Print" functions work fine when tested in 
MyModule.pm, so I know it is properly installed.

Any good feedback will be appreciated.

```
SECURE.CGI
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MyModule;

read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs) {
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
$value =~ tr/+/ /;
$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

### DATA VALIDATION IN MYMODULE.PM IS NOT OCCURRING#######  
$value = MyModule->scrub;
##########################################################

##### THIS WORKED WHEN "SCRUB" WAS EMBEDDED IN THIS SCRIPT #######  
##&scrub;

$userdata{$name} = $value;
}

$id1=$userdata{id1};
$id2=$userdata{id2};

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print" 
<BR>
<Table align=center width=1000 border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>
<TR><TD align=center>
<form action=\"http://###myserver###\" method=post>
<table border=1 bgcolor=#EAEAEA>
<TR><TD align=center colspan=3><B>Input Form</b></td></tr>
<TR><TD align=center><b>ID1</b><BR><input type=text name=id1></td></tr>
<TD align=center><b>ID2</b><BR><input type=text name=id2></td></tr>
<TD align=center><input type=submit value=submit name=submit></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<BR>
<table border=1 bgcolor=#EAEAEA >
<TR><TD align=center><B>Form Output</b></td></tr>
<TR><TD align=center><b>ID1</b></td></tr>
<TR><TD bgcolor=white align=center>&nbsp;  $id1</td></tr>
<TR><TD align=center><b>ID2</b></td></tr>
<TR><TD bgcolor=white align=center>&nbsp;  $id2</td></tr>
</table>

</TD></TR></table>
<BR>
</body>  </html>"; 
=======================================

MYMODULE.PM
package MyModule;

sub scrub {
$value =~ s/.html|.htm|.cgi|.php//g;    
$value =~ s/\///g;
$value =~ s/&|$|@|'|"|<|>|\^|\(|\)|=//g;
$value =~ s/onmouseup|onreset|onselect|onsubmit|onunload//g;    
return $value;
}
1;
```

Comment: Hello, time traveller from the year 1993!

Comment: Welp. Always `use strict; use warnings;`. `use CGI`; don't roll your own decoding. Read a Perl tutorial (keywords: lexical variables, heredocs, subroutine arguments).

Comment: I can think of several interesting ways to break that `scrub` function.

Comment: So can I.  What you see is not all there is; there is more code to filter erroneous input; I saw no reason to post all of it.

Answer (score 3):

There's so much wrong with the code, I don't know where to start. I'll leave the admonishments about style and technology to the peanut gallery.

The problem is that the subroutine uses a variable from an outer scope, but that's gone when the subroutine moved into a different package. Change the subroutine so it takes an argument instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the entity this code belongs to requires it as-is, for reasons I won't go into here.   My personal preference was to use "use CGI" and leave the validation regexes as they were in a subroutine, but it is not my choice.  Do you have a simple example of this argument?

Comment: `sub scrub { my ($value) = @_;` …………… `$value = MyModule->scrub($value);`

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was the simple fix:  

    sub scrub { 
    $value = $_[1];
    etc.